# Passing various parameters from C to Assembler

Tags: c, assembly, parameters, parameter-passing, nasm

I have to write an assembler subroutine `dswap(int, double*, int, double*, int)` which is called from a C program and assembled by NASM. My task is to manipulate the two given vectors (double*) based on the other three int parameters. Right now I am stuck to find out how exactly these parameters can be accessed in my assembler code and how to access specific elements from the vectors. Can you point me to some documentation/examples for this?

Comment: What is your target architecture/platform/calling convention?

Comment: Well I am writing 32bit code and compiling with gcc via MinGW on Windows. As for calling conventions I am just given the prototype `extern void dswap(int n, double* dx, int incx, double* dy, int incy)` with the instruction to code this in asm making me feel I am free to do what I want.

Comment: Ok, it's implicitly stated then that the calling convention is __cdecl. Next step is to determine Parameter passing scheme in MinGW's form of __cdecl.

Comment: You must be sure that your target linker will accept this assembly-produced object file. I assume you are using gcc/ld from MinGW. Is nasm also a part of MinGW?

Comment: nasm was not part of it though I downloaded it from the original homepage.

Comment: It would be mush easier to do this with Visual Studio. If you just could open its developer command prompt - you would have an access to its cl.exe, link.exe and masm.exe This would certainly guarantee you that the object file formats are the same - PE COFF. But in this situation I need time to investigate this. I'm not that keen on gcc/MinGW since I don't know what object file formats it outputs. And the same is true for nasm - I saw in the documentation of theirs that it supports COFF format.

Comment: What is the meaning of these int parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at "stack frames", and in case you're using x86, look at what the micro-coded instructions "enter" and "leave" do, but don't use them. Instead, use the coded out equivalent, to set up stack frame such that you can access your own passed arguments.

Consider that, in C, parameter handling is done such that you can pass many arguments to a function/subroutine, but only one can be returned.

Comment: He may additionally want to look into the different calling conventions used.  C using the c calling convention meaning that the parameters are pushed onto the stack in a very specific order that is slightly different from a calling convention such as stdcall.

Comment: If you are looking for a decent video tutorial of what a stack frame is and how stack frames grow I think I looked at this one when I was learning about them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSgrKtA0rJM

Comment: After some trial and error I was able to access the parameters via `[ebp + X]` where stats at 8 and increments in steps of 4 byte. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic That's the simple answer actually - on the stack. Once you save esp into ebp (push ebp; mov ebp, esp), then the return address is [ebp + 4] and your first parameter is [ebp + 8]. The sizes will vary if you have doubles or longs so your second param could be [ebp + 16] instead of [ebp + 12]!

Comment: Sizes won't vary - all these arguments will be pushed as dwords.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small investigation and it turns out MinGW gcc produces COFF-compliant object files. As to nasm - there is a command line - -f coff that you can use to force it produce COFF-format object file. Next it's quite restricted in form of defining procedures. In your assembly listing don't forget to specify SEGMENT _text before coding your actual function. The function must be defined in a way:

```
SEGMENT _text
global _dswap ;; underscore here is important - it's cdecl style.
_dswap:
push ebp ;; look below
mov ebp, esp ;; cdecl function prologue. Entering stack frame.
sub esp, 20h ;; This is for your local variables if needed.
;;do your work here. Use ebp as the origin for parameters. The very first passed parameter to the stack is ebp + 8(ebp + 4 is a return address).
;;
add esp, 20h ;; if you performed your local variables allocation. You can access them with mov eax, [esp + 10] for instance. But I recommend you to speci fy constants with EQU macro to make the code more readable. From your signature I see that you pass pointers to doubles. They reside on the regular stack. You have to pop them to floating point stack within this function before you can do something with these variables.
pop ebp ;; Leaving stack frame
ret ;; cdecl assumes that the caller shall clean parameters.
```

In your c file you just declare prototype without any extern keywords. Function prototypes are by default extern.

Did you intent to swap two double vectors through the use of this function?

As a hint - Open msys MinGW console(You must install every it's component before), type the following test.c file:

```
double foo(double lhl, double rhl)
{
    return lhl + rhl;
}

main()
{
    foo(4.5, 2.7);
    return 0;
}
```

compile it with gcc -c test.c
Next you will see test.o file. And this is the time to examine how this stuff works. You need to have dump bin utility or any other disassembly utility:

```
dumpbin /disasm:nobytes test.o > listing.asm
```

And yet I recommend you reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl